# conda create with 'anaconda' flag no longer installs all of the packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

It seems to me that when I used to run the following command from terminal:

```
conda create -n envname python=3.5 anaconda
```

Under `The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED` there was a list of several dozen packages, including `numpy`, `pandas`, `matplotlib`, etc.

Now when I run that command, it only lists six packages: `anaconda`, `pip`, `python`, `setuptools`, `vs2015_runtime` and `wheel`.

Is there something I need to do to get conda to install all of the default anaconda packages? Perhaps with that `anaconda` python library?

EDIT: This happens both on Windows 7 and on a Red Hat Linux server.

Comment: Did you install miniconda instead of the full anaconda distribution?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too when I installed python 3.5 a few months ago. I thought it was because many modules needed to be tested or updated at that time... Here is the conda cheatsheet, useful, but it undortunately does not address your problem. http://conda.pydata.org/docs/_downloads/conda-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: @JulesTamagnan, I definitely installed the full anaconda distribution. I even installed the latest full anaconda on a brand new Windows computer and got the same thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066873/create-anaconda-python-environment-with-all-packages Your question is generically addressed here.