# create anaconda python environment with all packages

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to create an anaconda python environment with **all** of the packages that Continuum includes in its default Anaconda installer. Based on some internet search I used the following command:

```
conda create -n env_full python=3
```

However, only handful of packages would be installed. Please see the screen shot.[image]

Kindly guide me to use correct commands.

Right now I am trying to do this on a desktop computer, but I would like to apply the same principles to the cluster facility.

Comment: `conda create -n env_full python=3 anaconda=4`

Answer (score 110, accepted):

To install all of the packages that Continuum includes in its default Anaconda installer, the simplest command is this:

```
conda create -n env_full anaconda
```

This will install the latest version of the `anaconda` package set, as compiled for your default version of Python (the one you used to install Anaconda originally). If you'd like to create an environment with a different version of Python, then just add that to the command line; e.g.

```
conda create -n env_full anaconda python=2.7
conda create -n env_full anaconda python=3.5
```

Comment: As I understand the command is 'conda create --name <envname> [list of packages]'. It so happens that the 'anaconda' package has as its requirements all the packages that are included in a default install, but in general if you wrote 'conda create --name <envname>  numpy scipy=1.6 blah_blah' you would get numpy, scipy=1.6, blah_blah and all their requirements? Is that correct?

Comment: Is there a way to install all packages in the default channel (i.e. not just the packages included in the anaconda installer)?

Comment: @user3731622 there is no practical circumstance where that is desirable. And it actually is not possible, as not all conda packages are compatible with each other.

Comment: Does this still work? Just tried this and got `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - anaconda`

Comment: fyi: to install older versions of the package lists, you can run the same command and just replace `anaconda` with `anaconda=<version>`. So, for example for the `2021.11` version: `conda create -n env_full anaconda=2021.11`

Answer (score 28):

Anaconda ships with a root env, this is named as base. You can use this as it is  or clone a new environment from it.

if you just want a environment with all the packages for day to day then you can use the base enviornment itself.

you can list the all available conda env on your machine as follows

```
 conda info --env
```

you will see a enviornment name base, activate it to use it

```
 source activate base
```

You can verify all the packages available in the env with following command ( This work with any env created with conda)

```
 conda list -n base
```

As I said above if you want a different env then you can clone base using following command

```
conda create --name <env_name> --clone base
```

Comment: I installed the tensoflor with command 'conda create -n tf tensorflow, conda activate tf and it showed success in all the steps, but giving me error "No module found" when I was importing. 

So I searched and found one solution, I had already created the another environment "tf" from anaconda navigator and then installed the new Jupyter. Now what happened is that in this new Jupiter my tensoflow works but all other previously installed libraries do not work(like sklearn), and in the old jupyter (base environment) tensorflow doesnt work and other libraries work.

So how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When I run this command:
`conda create -n env_full anaconda>`

I get a PackageNotFoundError. So I create a simple environment:
`conda create -n env_full`

and use this command to install all the anaconda default packages:
`conda install anaconda`

Comment: Is it just a typo? There's a "greater-than" sign at the end there, `anaconda>`