# Can run Tensorflow within conda env, but then cannot access other anacona modules (matplotlib, pandas etc)

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I have created a conda environment named tensorflow, and installed tensorflow within this environment following the official install guide (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#installing_with_anaconda)

When I activate the virtual environment I can import tensorflow, but cannot import other modules from anaconda such as pandas or matplotlib.

Do I need to re-install all the modules that I want again within the tensorflow environment?

If so, should I use conda rather than pip to install them?

Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks for the help, I'm quite new to virtual environments.

Comment: Possible Duplicate. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066873/create-anaconda-python-environment-with-all-packages?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: thank you! that thread was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I solved it by following steps (on mac):
(1) go to Anaconda Navigator (I installed Python via Anaconda)
(2) create a new environment called tensorflow;
 - See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDzAm25CORk&list=LLqPXFOcktYw3b6L9q_FAfgg&index=2&t=0s) for detailed steps
- I had issues with creating a new environment and solved it thanks to [this post](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11240) ("conda update conda")
(3) under "Environment", select the new "tensorflow" environment; on the right panel, filter "Not installed", search and install the missing modules
(4) Stay in Tensorflow environment - Go to "Home", install and launch jupyter notebook
(5) Go to jupyter and try import both tensorflow and any previously missing modules - should work this time.

Comment: I tried this Thanks. I was able to install tensorflow, Keras, pandas, but when no matter how many times I try to install matplotlib I get an error. It seems tensorflow and matplotlib  do not get on very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can either install the required packages manually by using `conda` or `pip`, or if you want to install all the packages that come by default you can use

```
conda install anaconda
```

Note this will download files of size more than 300MB.

Comment: just to clarify, I've already installed anaconda, and to access the anaconda packages within a conda environment I need to install anaconda a second time within that environment?