# cannot import name 'multiarray' in numpy with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, installation

I usually work with python 2.7 but this time i have to test a script in python3.

It is already installed on my computer, however when i start "python3", then go "import numpy", it show me "cannot import name 'multiarray'.

I even installed anaconda3 to test, but nothing happens

```
myName:~/anaconda3/bin$ python3
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in     <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'
```

I saw that it is looking in the lib/python2.7, but i cannot find what to do to get him search in the python3 library.

I already tried `python -m pip install numpy`, and tried to create a virtualenv in python3 but i still get the same error.

I cannot figure what to do. Can someone help me ?

I would like to add, i cannot start command with 'sudo' as i'm working on a client machine.

**edit:**

i tried @gehbiszumeis answer and got this:

```
myName:~ $ cd anaconda3/bin/
myName:~/anaconda3/bin $ source activate /home/myName/anaconda3
(base) myName:~/anaconda3/bin $ conda list numpy
# packages in environment at /home/myName/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
numpy                     1.14.3           py36hcd700cb_1  
numpy-base                1.14.3           py36h9be14a7_1  
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py36_0  
(base) myName:~/anaconda3/bin $ python3
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'
```

I see there is numpy 36 installed when i type conda list numpy, but it seems not to work.. Did i miss something ?

**edit2:**
After @Pal Szabo method, i tested command `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` and got this error :

```
(env) (base) myName:~/anaconda3/bin $ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myName/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/home/myName/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/home/myName/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import locale
  File "/home/myName/anaconda3/bin/env/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 16, in <module>
    import re
  File "/home/myName/anaconda3/bin/env/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in <module>
    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'`
```

It is a crazy mix between python3, python2.7 then again python3. I'm lost \o/

**edit3:**

I finally found my error.
It was a probleme with my PYTHONPATH, which was pointing somewhere where a .pth file was defined, with some hard link to python 2.7 libraries.
with a simple "unset PYTHONPATH" it works fine.
Thanks you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based what I can see from your code listing, it seems that the anaconda environment is not activated (this is usually indicated by the environments name in surrounding brackets () before the prompt). Because of that python3 tries to look for numpy and only finds the one you used for python 2.7 previously, which causes the error (see the `python2.7` error messages)

Try

```
source activate <your-anaconda-environment>
```

Then your prompt should look like this

```
(<your-anaconda-environment>) myName:~/anaconda3/bin$
```

Numpy should be contained in the standard anaconda environment. Try then to check if numpy is installed within your environment with

```
conda list numpy
```

If there is no numpy listed, try to install it with pip as you wrote before.

Comment: I tested your solution and edited my post. Could not answer you properly as it is more than 5xx characters. Is this the right way, to edit the post ?

Comment: Try to start python by only calling `(base) myName:~/anaconda3/bin $ python` instead of `...python3`. It seems you are still calling the python not belonging to the environment

Comment: same things happens :(

Comment: wow, odd! Ok, next thing would be to set up a completely new anaconda environment with standard packages and python 3.6. 

Try `conda create -n new_env_full anaconda python=3.6`

See the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066873/create-anaconda-python-environment-with-all-packages) for more information.

Afterwards start the environment by `source activate env_full` and try to call python and import numpy again

Comment: I did exactly what you mentionned, created new-env-full, it said in the install list it installed numpy "1.14.3-py36hcd700cb_1", so i guess the 'py36' mean python3.6 so it should be the right one.
However, when i go in the env and type "python", then "import numpy", i still have the error and 'python2.7' in the traceback. Same with python3 then import numpy.

Comment: okay, then maybe your PYTHONPATH variable is pointing to an incorrect numpy. Try in the terminal `unset PYTHONPATH` before sourcing your environment

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, took me several hours to figure it out.

In my case, the `PYTHONPATH` was set to `/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/` 
changing it to `/Users/xxx/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` resolved the issue. 
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If want to use python3, use pip3 instead of pip:

```
 pip3 install numpy
```

You can try these too in terminal:

```
rm -Rf env
virtualenv -p python3 env
source env/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip3 install numpy
```

Also make sure that the first line of your script is

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Don't write anything, even comments, before this.

Comment: I did tried again `pip3 install numpy`, saying "successfully installed numpy-1.11.0" but i still have the same error when "import numpy"

Comment: I see. Is your first line #!/usr/bin/python3?

Comment: I did not even started a python file. I just typed python3 in command, and then "import numpy".
But if i try with a script, put `#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy` in the script and start it, it get me the same error.

Comment: Well, if virtualenv -p python3 env followed by source env/bin/activate and then starting python3 also didn't work than I don't know whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem changing the Python's version on VS Code. I was working with Python 3.7.4, now with the 3.7.8 one.

When I installed Numpy, it was stored in the folder of Python3.6. So I think that u could try to change the path or just change the Python's version