# How to use Anaconda base environment in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

I am trying to set up **base** environment of Anaconda to use in PyCharm. There is no such option in the settings (either "system interpreter" or "create new environment"; I had to use "system interpreter"). I managed to setup "activate.bat" for the terminal, but "base" environment is not activated during debug or usual runs - as a result I get errors (compared to just run in Anaconda console - everything is fine). What should I do?

Answer (score 12):

You need to select `python.exe` from the base Anaconda, e.g.

[image]

It's also a better choice to use [2019.1 EAP build](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/), as there's a fix to conda activation in the terminal there. You don't really need to select `activate.bat` as a terminal.

Comment: I wonder why this path does not show up by default as one of the existing environment options in pycharm inpreters --> conda --> exisiting interpreters

Comment: I was not able to see it on the list when you click on the tab. In case you do not find the base env on the drop-down  you can always type it as such:
C:\Users\userX\Anaconda3\python.exe

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Mac OS user (Catalina).

I found my Conda base environment here:
/Users/donald/anaconda3/bin/python3

Fortunately pip3 and Conda (base) work together pretty seamlessly with this setup. So this environment should show up as "Python 3.8 (base)" (or similar) separate from your other Conda environments.

[Mac OS New Project Interpreter Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rclUf.png)

Answer (score 2):

Windows Solution:

Go to File -> Settings -> Python Interpreter -> Add (Gear symbol) -> VirtualEnv Environment  -> Exisiting Environment (C:...\Anaconda3\python.exe)

This sequence will create the Python (base) Interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Linux user.

Before use anaconda in PyCharm i installed anaconda like anaconda web site says:

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/

Later i tried to use it in PyCharm in the anaconda environment option but it installed everything again even though anaconda was already installed on mi PC.

I solved that selecting a "Pure Pyhton" project, "Existing interpreter" and in "Interpreter" add the python executable from the anaconda installation. The picture is an example of my project configuration.

[image: Anaconda Project]

Answer (score 0):

I am using macOS and I have got the base python environment in the following location

```
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

Just add in the location in the interpreter section under existing environment option

Answer (score 0):

I tried selecting the 'python.exe' file in the main Anaconda installation directory as selecting bin folder did not work for me.

This one gave me the base env :

```
'..\Programs\Anaconda\python.exe'
```

Please note that I have installed Anaconda in Programs folder instead of the default  'C:\Users\ .. ' directory during installation. You should look for the .exe file in the location where you have installed Anaconda.

Python version 3.8 and Pycharm 2021.1 community edition.

Answer (score 0):

I have a `system interpreter` option and point it to anaconda base `python.exe` file

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy2w9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add that you might prefer to clone the base first and use the cloned virtual environment, so that you can update/install packages without worrying to break some dependencies etc. Incidentally this is also an easier way to use the full package compared to setting up the base environment.

In your prompt/terminal, you can use the following command (per [instructions in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48946093/6054915)):

```
conda create --name <env_name> --clone base
```

where instead of <env_name> you write the desired name for your environment.

Then you can use the newly cloned environment, which will include all the packages from your anaconda, by following the instructions in the **"Configuring a PyCharm Project with an existing conda environment"** section [in the official page](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/).