# Why installing many times the same applications in different environments? (Anaconda-Navigator)

Tags: installation, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, environment

I am using Anaconda-Navigator and I noticed that when I create a new environment it does not have **any of the applications** (Spyder, Jupyter-Notebook, etc) installed on it.

I did some research and noticed that, indeed, people do talk about "installing **app X** on **environment env**"

Why is that? What is the difference of doing that compared to having only one installation and when launching the application select which environment to work with?
Is there an inconvenient with doing so?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Are you trying to create new conda virtual environments? If so is this old question helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066873/create-anaconda-python-environment-with-all-packages

Comment: Hi, thanks, it's not the same since I they are referring to packages (ex. SciPy, Pandas, Seaborn, etc), while I am talking about applications (ex. Spyder, Jupyter-Notebook,etc)