# I have a simple question about creating new conda environment with packages

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm, anaconda3

There's a problem about creating new env with **anaconda3.**

Before I explain specifically, Here is the result of running **'conda list'** in the root folder.

[image]

There are too many packages to include in the screenshots **and all the basic packages like scipy, numpy and matplotlib are included.**

---

However, **when creating a new env here, only some packages are installed as follows.**

What I expected was that I wanted packages like scipy and numpy to be installed as well, but that doesn't work.

[image]

What is the problem?

Here is my whole setting

- ubuntu 20.04
- pycharm community
- python 3.9
- anaconda

Comment: This question covers the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066873/create-anaconda-python-environment-with-all-packages. A new conda environment contains the minimum set of packages it needs. To add, e.g. the scientific stack, you need to specify additional packages. A convenient way to do that is to install the `anaconda` meta-package with `conda create -n env_full anaconda python=3.9`.

Comment: @PascalBugnion Thank you for answer. Actually, it's a command I've already tried before asking a question.

Nonetheless, the reason I left the question was that it took too long to check for conflicts during installation.

I looked for other issues, but I also saw people who take as little as 24 hours and as long as a week.

Did you do that too?

Comment: I just tried this and it looks like the `anaconda` metapackage isn't yet compatible with Python 3.9. Doing `conda create -n env_full anaconda python=3.8` takes about ~5 minutes on a cloud VM (maybe slightly longer on a home wifi). If you really need 3.9, then you'll have to list the packages you need manually with something like: `conda create -n env_full2 scipy pandas scikit-learn python=3.9`. Note that just choosing those three brings in much of the scientific stack they depend on, like numpy, joblib etc.